# Web Scrape Failing - Beautiful Soup

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape a web page using Beautiful Soup to get a list of 2017 Biggest Tunes.

I've tried a number of references in the html source from `div` to `ul` to `span` to `li` but I cant seem to get anything out of the page.

I cant work it out as I've written similar code to parse other sites that has worked. Here's my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b09jvtff'

# Opening up URL and grabbing info
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
container_a = page_soup.findAll("span",{"class": "artist"})
print(container_a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the requests being done when you load the page in your chrome browser, you will realise that this is the URL which will contain the information that you need: `http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b09jvtdf/segments.inc`. Replace the URL with this one and you will get what you need.

Also, if you debug the HTML that you're retrieving currently you will see that what you're looking for is not there.

**P.S. It is probably illegal to scrape this website. Check T&Cs.**

Comment: Thanks Luke Bajada, I wasn't aware of the legality, I was only downloading a list to save writing it.

Comment: If this worked out for you, can you accept my answer?